# How does one access a file within a directory in a zip file without creating any new files?

Tags: java, unzip, zip

I'm working on a java project that requires me to access a file within multiple embedded zip files and directories.

For example, archive1.zip/archive1/archive2.zip/archive2/directory1/file_that_I_need.txt.

It would be a lot easier if when each zip file was extracted, it would immediately list its contents but instead there's a folder inside that contains all the contents.

The examples I found online deal with zip files that, when extracted, contain the files they need to access but I can't find any that deal with accessing files within a directory in a zip file. Any advice on this would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no difference. You give the path in the ZIP file which can include a directory.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. Would you mean that code like: zis = ZipInputStream( new FileInputStream(file) ) ; would work? Assuming that File file = new File("archive1.zip/archive1/archive2.zip").

Comment: Loading a zip from inside a zip is a bit of madness but you can do it. You need to go through the entries of archive1.zip until you find the InputStream for archive2.zip. Using an ZipInputStream on that, you need to scan it for the file you actually need.

Comment: The only entry for archive1.zip though IS a directory. How do I access the files inside that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the prohibition against creating new files, you're pretty much stuck with [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html). When you find the `ZipEntry` that corresponds to the embedded archive, you then read its stream to find the actual file. You can proceed recursively through as many levels of archives as you want.

This works OK if you're looking to process a single file. However, re-reading the archives for multiple files can be expensive. A better solution is to at least open the outer archive as a [ZipFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html), which memory-maps the actual file.

If you can then extract the contained archives into a temporary directory and open them as `ZipFile`s as well, you'll probably see a big speed increase (as long as you're pulling multiple files from each embedded archive).

Comment: Thanks, your first paragraph looks like the way I want to go. How would do that though?<br/>
<br/>
Would code like:<br/>
ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream( new FileInputStream("archive1.zip") ;<br/><br/>
//insert loop here
ZipEntry zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry() ;<br/>
<br/>Would getNextEntry() recursively go in directories as well?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new here, formatting is terrible. In essence, would using the function zipInputStream.getNextEntry() recursively return files in embedded directories??

Comment: I would write a function `ZipInputStream findFile(ZipInputStream in, String name)` that iterates all the entries in `in`, and returns the stream for the entry that matches `name`. You could either break apart your path beforehand (in which case it's actually iterative), or break it inside the method (in which case it's recursive).

Comment: Also: read the documentation for `ZipInputStream` regarding closing a stream. You don't want to close your streams too early.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that's really helpful. I assume the best way to iterate through the entries in 'in' will be getNextEntry. What if the zip file contains a directory with files in it. Will getNextEntry only return the name of the directory or will it go inside the directory and return the files in there too?

Answer (score 0):

You might also look at http://truezip.java.net/  I've used an older version of it, and its quite a bit more powerful than the support that's built into Java.  I think there is also an Apache Commons library for reading files from within nested archive structures.